# why when I press enter on the filter the table returns all the values?

Tags: tabulator

I copied the code from http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/filter#header-filters.

when I press the enter key on the filter values ​​the table returns all the values ​​eliminating the filter.

attached fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9L01mc6v/1/

```
function buildValues(){
    success({
        start:start.value,
        end:end.value,
    });
}

function keypress(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        buildValues();
    }

    if(e.keyCode == 27){
        cancel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling buildValues() again on Enter keypress ? You have already binded it to change and blur events you are just calling the same function thrice.

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dota2pro/mfqsdcu3/)

```
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
 // buildValues(); // Commented this
}
```